# Converting an Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment to System.Net.Mail.Attachment in c#

Tags: c#, casting, outlook-addin, outlook-2007, email-attachments

I'm currently programming an addon to Outlook 2007 and I ran into a problem when I tried to Serialize an attachment.  Although System.Net.Mail Attachments have a ContentStream that I can use to serialize the data, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook Attachments does not.  Unfortunately, the only type of attachment I can get directly from Outlook is the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook one. I've searched around a bit and haven't been able to find anything similar.

```
MailItem item = getMailObj(e);    
String dataSend = serializeAttachment((System.Net.Mail.Attachment)item.Attachments[1]);
```

As you can see, I tried typecasting the initial attachment, but i was given an Invalid Cast Exception:

> Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'System.__ComObject' to class type
>   'System.Net.Mail.Attachment'.
>   Instances of types that represent COM
>   components cannot be cast to types
>   that do not represent COM components;
>   however they can be cast to interfaces
>   as long as the underlying COM
>   component supports QueryInterface
>   calls for the IID of the interface.

I also cannot just put

```
System.Net.Mail.Attachment newAtt = item.Attachments[1];
```

As VisualStudio 2010 just tells me to typecast it. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that types can be casted or converted. Just read content of Outlook attachment and write it to Mail.Attachment.

Comment: I've tried doing this, but unfortunately the Microsoft version of Attachment doesn't have a ContentStream for me to transfer information to the Net version of Attachment.  The only properties that I can transfer are filename, size and type.

Comment: You may use GetTemporaryFilePath() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachment.gettemporaryfilepath.aspx or SaveAsFile() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachment.saveasfile.aspx methods to get content of Outlook attachment.

Comment: I tried using GetTemporaryFilePath() but I'm getting the following error when I try to use it 'Cannot access this attachment in the temporary files folder.  Use this method in an attachment event to obtain the temporary file path.' I would also prefer not having to save the file with SaveAsFile().

Comment: I think you will need to use SaveAsFile method, because on first look there are no ways to obtain attachment content. Use Path.GetTempFileName method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx and save attachment contnent in that temporary file.